# Jquery call input id

Tags: jquery

```
<input id="IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm:stateNumber4" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="text" title="Улсын дугаар" name="IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm:stateNumber4" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false"></input>

jQuery(function ($) {
$("#stateNumber4").mask("9999aaa");;
```

How i call input id for this Jquery.

Thanx all. But still not working. 
My XHML inputText is here:

```
<p:inputText id="stateNumber4" type="text" value="#{isCaseReviewsController.current.isReviewsItemsAPK.stateNumber}" title="Улсын дугаар" required="true" requiredMessage="Улсын дугаар оруулна уу"/>
```

Compile after Inspect element it is:

```
<input id="IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm:stateNumber4" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="text" title="Улсын дугаар" name="IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm:stateNumber4" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false"></input>
```

Input mask is working another page, but that page haven't form or dialog. My own this page has dialog->form->input. 
I think main problem is jquery function couldn't call my input id.

Comment: #IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm:stateNumer4 doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `:` in id so you need to escape it.

Use

```
$("#IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm\\:stateNumber4").mask("9999aaa");
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

**OR**

Use [**Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("[id='IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm:stateNumber4']").mask("9999aaa");
```

**However, I would recommend you to remove `:` from the ID**

Answer (score 0):

Remove colon ":" from id. Let it be `<input id="IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm_stateNumber4" ...>`.
`$("#IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm_stateNumber4")` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it, currently is understood as filter selector:

```
$("#IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm\\:stateNumber4").mask("9999aaa");;
```

See this [article for more information](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)

Also consider following example:

```
<input id="ehsan.sajjad" type="text"/>
```

Now if i write it to change its value using:

```
$("#ehsan.sajjad").val("SOmeValue"); // will not work as . will understood it that element with id ehsan and class sajjad
```

But escaping the **.** using `\\` will make it work correctly:

```
$("#ehsan\\.sajjad").val("SOmeValue"); // now will work now it understands its id whose value is ehsan.sajjad
```

### DEMO EXAMPLE:

```js
$(function(){


$("#ehsan\\.sajjad").val("Ehsan Sajjad");

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ehsan.sajjad"/>
```

While this will not work:

```js
$(function(){


$("#ehsan.sajjad").val("Ehsan Sajjad");

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ehsan.sajjad"/>
```

Comment: $("#IsCaseReviewsAddCarDlg\\.IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm\\.stateNumber4").mask("9999aaa"); not working.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("##IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm\\:stateNumber4").mask("9999aaa");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm:stateNumber4" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="text" title="Улсын дугаар" name="IsCaseReviewsAddCarForm:stateNumber4" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"
aria-multiline="false"></input>
```

Also refer this question for valid id - [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)